# Boot ISO from HDD from UEFI?

Tags: boot, usb, iso-image, uefi, efi

I have a Windows 8 To Go Entreprise HDD, which boots both on BIOS and UEFI systems (I'm wondering how that's done, because I need that too).

Now, I see the HDD I use for that windows is an MBR HDD, it consist of a 350 MB FAT32 partition which holds the booting file to boot the second, NTFS partition which contains thw Windows 8 To Go operating system.

on the second partition I have placed a few ISO files under \partition2\ISO\.

for example:

Win8Install.ISO
Win7Install.ISO
HirenBootCD.ISO

when booting from BIOS into the system, and using EasyBCD to create startup entries for the ISO's, the ISO's boot fine, from BIOS.

But when going into UEFI another BCD table is used, so I re-added the ISO's to the UEFI selection, but when selecting the ISO boot created by EasyBCD on the UEFI boot selection, I get the following error:

[image]

How do I make UEFI boot ISO files or FAT32 partitions with grub4dos installed? They work fine on BIOS boot.

Seems windows To Go can boot from BOTH BIOS AND UEFI, on an MBR(!! [I have read UEFI can only boot from GPT, lies, lies everywhere]) disk. So this should be possible, please help me.

Edit: Activity Edit.

Comment: Well, added a bounty and comment so --up--.

Comment: Does this have any relevance to your question? http://reboot.pro/topic/18182-uefi-multi-make-multi-boot-usb-drive/

Comment: Error 0xc000007b may relate to mismatch between 32- and 64-bit, so may be caused by 32-bit code trying to boot a 64-bit OS. Are you sure you are using grub4dos ? Its latest release dates from 2009 and knows nothing about UEFI.

Comment: Another question: Why are you booting read-only ISO instead of VHD? Windows 7 & 8 have the ability to boot directly to VHD, no boot-manager required.

Comment: and when I create, for example a windows 98 VHD, it CAN boot into it? (I mean, start the boot process). I have a 1TB portable HDD and I need to make it a rescue HDD for BIOS and UEFI

Comment: booting from FAT32/NTFS/ext partitions would be cool too.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want (1) A boot disk that can boot multiple operating systems where all the OSs are fully installed on the USB disk, or (2) A multi-boot USB that can boot and install/repair multiple operating systems on the computer you are booting and working more like multiple CDs. You cannot have both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error 0xc000007b may relate to mismatch between 32- and 64-bit, so may be caused by 32-bit grub4dos trying to boot a 64-bit OS.
The grub4dos latest release dates from 2009 and knows nothing about UEFI,
so shouldn't be used.

You should probably start from scratch and use the tool [UEFI MULTI](http://reboot.pro/topic/18182-uefi-multi-make-multi-boot-usb-drive/).
The purpose of this tool is described as :

> Tool to format USB-stick for Booting with Boot Manager Menu on BIOS or
>   UEFI computer and Tool to make USB-Stick having two partitions - FAT32
>   Boot partition for WIM or ISO and NTFS System partition for VHD.
>   Option to Install Grub4dos in MBR BootCode, which allows BIOS computer
>   to boot directly from USB with Grub4dos Menu. Option to make Boot
>   Manager and Grub4dos Menu on UFD to boot UEFI + BIOS directly from USB
>   with Boot Manager Menu.

This link describes the procedure of how to create the USB disk.
The procedure is much too long to reproduce here.

Although this tool claims it can do what you want,
I have no personal experience with it.

As regarding your question about how can one disk work for both BIOS and UEFI,
this magic is probably achieved by using a [Hybrid MBR](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html),
which is a format of the disk that looks as if it is both MBR and GPT.
This is possible since GPT by design does not use the disk boot sector used by MBR.
The size of a Hybrid MBR disk is limited to 2 TB, the maximum size of an MBR disk.

Comment: Grub4DOS uses BIOS routines and since UEFI dosn't provide BIOS routines it won't work with it. It's also 16bit code that uses real mode to address up to 1mb of memory not 32bit.

Comment: I think you mean 2 TB, not 2 GB, since that's the max for MBR disks.

Comment: @IceMage: Thanks, I surely meant just that, but my fingers just didn't get the message.